# laravel push notification use GCM error

Tags: laravel, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Use Android Google GCM.
The error is

> Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection gcm-http.googleapis.com

```
$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')
    ->to($devices);
$collection->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
    $collection->send($message);
```

I use SSL..
I dont know whats going wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to produce this error?

Comment: https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/89

Comment: the code is:$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')
            ->to($devices);
        $collection->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
        $collection->send($message);                          The 'sslverifypeer' is already false here...